# For some reason config.gem 'xapian-fu' fails despite gem 'xapian-fu' works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For some reason when I try to do config.gem include for this particular gem package it always says its missing. I tried gem 'xapian-fu' and that works just fine! I am sure its not multi gem repository issue as I use the environment in regular basis and has no problem about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK turns out I figured out the answer myself :P

config.gem 'xapian-fu', :lib=>'xapian_fu'

The problem seems because the lib file is being named with the underscore while the gem itself is named with hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

Glad you figured out the issue, there is a good Railscast about [Gem Dependencies](http://railscasts.com/episodes/110-gem-dependencies) that covers the whole config.gem setup in depth.

One additional thing, I'd highly recommend explicitly setting the gem version number you want installed as otherwise you're risking pulling a newer version of a gem that may have compatibility issues.

Comment: yeah agree, I am just playing around it for now, when I do something serious I would definitely lock it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote xapian-fu and this naming inconsistency is a bug, sorry!

It's fixed in the latest version, so you don't need to specify the :lib option any more (the library is now available as both xapian_fu and xapian-fu).